# Why doesn't the AJAX request respond to either fail or success?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

project/add.html:

```
<input type="text" id="txtmaterialname" class="form-control" name="txtName">
```

project/assets/js/script.js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#txtmaterialname').on('focusout',function(){
           var materialname = $("#txtmaterialname").val();
           checkmaterial(materialname);
       });
 });

function checkmaterial(materialname)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../chk_materialexist.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{materialname: materialname},
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        },
        fail: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
           alert('request failed');
        }
    });
}
```

project/chk_materialexist.php:

```
 <?php
      if(isset($_POST['materialname']))
      {
         $materialname = $_POST['materialname'];
             echo "$materialName";
      }
      else
        echo 'noo';
   ?>
```

I'm using Microsoft Edge .. I tried putting an `alert` in the script and it worked .. I tried the PHP file and it worked alone but the AJAX request didn't return an answer.

Comment: put a console.log() above $.ajax. Does it pass the console.log()?

Comment: Try an absolute url for the ajax url -  `url: '/project/chk_materialexist.php'`

Comment: try to call manually `checkmaterial()` from the console: does it alert?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio no

Comment: maybe the error in jquery libraries? but other jquery functions are working

Answer (score 2):

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) doesn't support a `fail` **option**, the option is called `error`. (It supports a [`fail` method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) on what it returns, but that's different.)

Change `fail` to `error`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is `url: ../../chk_materialexist.php,`. You need to put quotes inside that.

`url: '../../chk_materialexist.php',`